# Using Default UserCreationForm does not show error if the passwords do not match

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

Using Default UserCreationForm from django.contrib.auth.forms does not show error if the passwords do not match. I do not want to create a custom model.

Here is the code from my views.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        print(response.POST)
        form = UserCreationForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(response,"register/register.html",{"form":form})
```

register.html code

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Register </title>    
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>This is the Registration page</h1>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought the message would be automatically displayed. Am I missing something?
Edit: None of the error message are being displayed like password length < 8, all numeric passwords, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You each time create a *new* form, you should render the one that is invalid:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def register(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()  # 🖘 only for a GET request
    return render(response, 'register/register.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.